# Projectile null value

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I'm trying to make a shooter game but when I shoot while there are still bullets spawned I get these error codes:

```
ArgumentNullException: Value cannot be null.
Parameter name: source
UnityEngine.AudioSource.Play () (at <ec7b0cef068d42fea98bc6f00449b0e2>:0)
RayCastShootComplete+<ShotEffect>d__12.MoveNext () (at Assets/Let's Try 
Shooter/Scripts/CompletedScripts/RayCastShootComplete.cs:87)
UnityEngine.SetupCoroutine.InvokeMoveNext (System.Collections.IEnumerator enumerator, 
System.IntPtr returnValueAddress) (at <7d87237cea3743d093e22c5b98f74fba>:0)
UnityEngine.MonoBehaviour:StartCoroutine(IEnumerator)
RayCastShootComplete:Update() (at Assets/Let's Try 
Shooter/Scripts/CompletedScripts/RayCastShootComplete.cs:41)

NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object
RayCastShootComplete.Update () (at Assets/Let's Try 
Shooter/Scripts/CompletedScripts/RayCastShootComplete.cs:44)
```

Here is the code it is referencing:

using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;

public class RayCastShootComplete : MonoBehaviour {

```
public int gunDamage = 1;                                           // Set the number of hitpoints that this gun will take away from shot objects with a health script
public float fireRate = 0.25f;                                      // Number in seconds which controls how often the player can fire
public float weaponRange = 50f;                                     // Distance in Unity units over which the player can fire
public float hitForce = 100f;                                       // Amount of force which will be added to objects with a rigidbody shot by the player
public Transform gunEnd;                                            // Holds a reference to the gun end object, marking the muzzle location of the gun

private Camera fpsCam;                                              // Holds a reference to the first person camera
private WaitForSeconds shotDuration = new WaitForSeconds(0.07f);    // WaitForSeconds object used by our ShotEffect coroutine, determines time laser line will remain visible
private AudioSource gunAudio;                                       // Reference to the audio source which will play our shooting sound effect
private LineRenderer laserLine;                                     // Reference to the LineRenderer component which will display our laserline
private float nextFire;                                             // Float to store the time the player will be allowed to fire again, after firing


void Start () 
{
    // Get and store a reference to our LineRenderer component
    laserLine = GetComponent<LineRenderer>();

    // Get and store a reference to our AudioSource component
    gunAudio = GetComponent<AudioSource>();

    // Get and store a reference to our Camera by searching this GameObject and its parents
    fpsCam = GetComponentInParent<Camera>();
}


void Update () 
{
    // Check if the player has pressed the fire button and if enough time has elapsed since they last fired
    if (Input.GetButtonDown("Fire1") && Time.time > nextFire) 
    {
        // Update the time when our player can fire next
        nextFire = Time.time + fireRate;

        // Start our ShotEffect coroutine to turn our laser line on and off
        StartCoroutine (ShotEffect());

        // Create a vector at the center of our camera's viewport
        Vector3 rayOrigin = fpsCam.ViewportToWorldPoint (new Vector3(0.5f, 0.5f, 0.0f));

        // Declare a raycast hit to store information about what our raycast has hit
        RaycastHit hit;

        // Set the start position for our visual effect for our laser to the position of gunEnd
        laserLine.SetPosition (0, gunEnd.position);

        // Check if our raycast has hit anything
        if (Physics.Raycast (rayOrigin, fpsCam.transform.forward, out hit, weaponRange))
        {
            // Set the end position for our laser line 
            laserLine.SetPosition (1, hit.point);

            // Get a reference to a health script attached to the collider we hit
            ShootableBox health = hit.collider.GetComponent<ShootableBox>();

            // If there was a health script attached
            if (health != null)
            {
                // Call the damage function of that script, passing in our gunDamage variable
                health.Damage (gunDamage);
            }

            // Check if the object we hit has a rigidbody attached
            if (hit.rigidbody != null)
            {
                // Add force to the rigidbody we hit, in the direction from which it was hit
                hit.rigidbody.AddForce (-hit.normal * hitForce);
            }
        }
        else
        {
            // If we did not hit anything, set the end of the line to a position directly in front of the camera at the distance of weaponRange
            laserLine.SetPosition (1, rayOrigin + (fpsCam.transform.forward * weaponRange));
        }
    }
}


private IEnumerator ShotEffect()
{
    // Play the shooting sound effect
    gunAudio.Play ();

    // Turn on our line renderer
    laserLine.enabled = true;

    //Wait for .07 seconds
    yield return shotDuration;

    // Deactivate our line renderer after waiting
    laserLine.enabled = false;
}
```

}

Does anyone know what I should do?

For clarification it is a post-apocalyptic game where the protagonist is trying to find a new home.

Comment: Is there an `AudioClip` assigned to your `gunAudio`?

Answer (score 0):

Be sure your game object which the script is attached to has a LineRenderer and AudioSource with a valid audio attached to it. I'm on my phone right now, but based on the error message, I think you can comment the lines using these objects (gunAudio and laserLine) to see if this is the problem.

You can get more details about AudioSource here: https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/AudioSource.html

Answer (score 0):

ArgumentNullException occurs because you tried to access method from `laserLine/ gunAudio` but they are null. `GetComponent` alone only retrieves components from the GameObject this script is attached to. So make sure the LineRenderer, AudioSource, and this script are all attached to the same GameObject.

A [reference](https://www.youtube.com/shorts/WbuQNmbwecc) if it helps.

The NullReferenceException is probably caused by the same issue. ( `laserLine` and `gunAudio` being null )